# How can I make the semicircle slanted and curved at the side and the bottom using turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, shapes, python-turtle

```
t = turtle.Pen()
t.left(90)
for x in range(180):
    t.forward(1)
    t.right(1)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(115)
```

The pink eye that is slanted and curved at the sides and the bottom:

[image: screenshot of panda icon]

Comment: Maybe Bezier curves? [How to get the points of a bezier curve/parabola using 3 unique points on a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737686/how-to-get-the-points-of-a-bezier-curve-parabola-using-3-unique-points-on-a-grap) or https://github.com/LQR471814/Curve-Tortoise

Answer (score 0):

Be a turtle.

Go find a floor with square tiles.
Place a penny on an intersection,
or use some convenient pillar or corner -- that's the origin!

Now take tiny steps and change heading same as the program says,
to see where you end up.

You wrote:

```
for x in range(180):
    t.forward(1)
    t.right(1)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(115)
```

This corresponds to taking baby steps and shifting where you point
*ever* *so* *slightly* with each one.

But look at that 90° turn! Too much. Followed by a giant step of 115 px.
I think this is what you meant instead:

```
for x in range(180):
    t.forward(1)
    t.right(1)
t.right(90)
t.forward(115)
```

That is to say, let's draw an arc with total circumference of 180 units,
with curvature totaling 180°.
And then, *outside* the loop, after it has completed,
let's hang a sharp rightie and take one giant step forward.

This is python.
Indent matters.
A lot.

Comment: Thank you! Now it has become a proper semi circle...but I still don't know how to make it curve to make it look like the panda eye :/

Comment: Currently you have a giant circle with large radius and a pair of pointy ends. To smooth them off, you will want to insert small circles where we turn more than one degree with each baby step. And then a straight line joining both of them would be fine for now.